# Issue with specifying the file name path

Tags: python

How and where I specify the path in the code below to the folder name where I want to export the data? I would like the 'hello_world.xlsx' workbook to be stored in a specific folder.

I am new to python.

```
    import xlsxwriter
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello_world.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: What if you do `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("C:\Documents\MyFolder\hello_world.xlsx')`?

Comment: Do you want something like a 'save as' function in apps?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I had it this way before I posted the question however for whatever reason it came with a syntax error. After I got your reply I tried it again ant it works now fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used xlsx, but I'd bet that where you specify the file and type (`...Workbook("")`) you can substitute with a specific directory along with the file name (`C:\\fileName.xlsx`)